# How many keys are there in leaf node of B+ trees?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

I am going through B+ trees. I am having a doubt that what is the minimum number of keys in a B+ tree leaf node ?

I am reading from the following references, but they are saying something else

1). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

2). http://www.cburch.com/cs/340/reading/btree/

3). http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/08sp/lectures/11-b-trees.pdf

The last link uses some letter L for leaf node.

Can someone clarify, what must be the exact coount of keys in a leaf node ?

Answer (score 0):

Min: `1`, because a tree with just one entry must be possible.

Max: `<branch factor> - 1`, because that's how the branch factor is defined.

Comment: In 2nd link, it is specified floor(n/2) . is this right?